# Chrome viewport resizing not showing?

Tags: google-chrome, resize, google-chrome-devtools, pixel

Probably doing something dumb...but when I enter the console in Chrome and try resizing the screen, I don't see the pixel values anymore. What's up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Chrome version 49.0.2623.87? If so, this is a [known bug and has been mark as fixed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=582421). The feature will be available in upcoming version 50 according to [this discussion](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/sWPkHpMZlpE). For the time being, maybe you can install an [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh) or alternatively use the [developer version](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) where this issue doesn't exist.

Comment: Yup, that's my version. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue working locally with the viewport extension. Apparently, the problem was that I was calling my webpage directly with the mouse as a normal file.  After calling it appropriately from a local apache web server (xampp) the issue was solved.